# Сохранение данных в PasswordBox при повторной навигации на Page

Tags: c#, wpf

Создаю несколько страниц Page с набором контролов.
Осуществляю навигацию помощью

```
((NavigationWindow)window).NavigationService.Navigate(какой-то объект страницы)
```

Если сделать так:

```
Page page1 = new Page();
Page page2 = new Page();

((NavigationWindow)window).NavigationService.Navigate(page1);

// Пользователь вводит данные, затем переходит
((NavigationWindow)window).NavigationService.Navigate(page2);

// Пользователь вводит данные, затем вспоминает, что что-то не ввёл на предыдущей странице
((NavigationWindow)window).NavigationService.Navigate(page1);
```

При повторном переходе на page1 сохраняются все введённые в контролы данные, кроме контрола PasswordBox. Как сделать так, чтобы при повторной навигации на страницу сохранялись введённые данные в PasswordBox?

Comment: *сохраняются все введённые в контролы данные* у вас там привязки или что? Вообще при такой навигации, вроде, создается новый экземпляр страницы. Почему не используете `NavigationBack` (или как он там называется)?

Comment: "Почему не используете NavigationBack (или как он там называется)?" - путь движения по страницам динамический, в т.ч. и в обратную сторону

Comment: "Вообще при такой навигации, вроде, создается новый экземпляр страницы" - нет, в параметрах передаётся созданный объект страницы

Comment: Для PasswordBox привязок нет

Comment: Попробовал снять привязку для TextBox, что-то ввести, перейти вперед-назал - да, результат не сохраняется. По ходу выводится только для тех контролов, у которых есть привязка на поля, содержащиеся в данном Page

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10783583/6766879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это стандартное поведение и сделано преднамеренно разработчиками фреймворка. Сделано это из всё тех же соображений безопасности. Вам придется позаботиться о сохранении и восстановлении пароля вручную.